# USB UFP and DFP - differences

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, usb, usb-device, usb-c

How to understand or differentiate between a USB upstream-facing port and a downstream-facing port?

Just want to understand it to place the resistors on the CCx pins in case of using a Type-C connector.

Comment: One way to learn the difference is to read the USB specification. It's freely availble, explains difference of UFP and DFP, including the resistors for Type-C connector CC pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to understand or differentiate between a USB upstream-facing port
> and a downstream-facing port?

At the very basic level, an upstream-facing port is a port on a device. Therefore the device port must have 5.1k resistors down to ground on both CC pins.

The "downstream-facing port" is a port on USB host, and a provider of power by default. It must have two pull-up resistors (or corresponding current sources) on each CC pin. The value of the resistors (56k,22k,10k) indicates the port power capability.

More details can be found here,

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/327946/117785
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/442152/117785
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/390723/117785